# MySQL update job with LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to update a value based on the result of left joins and group by?

I want to be able to update category with current jobs to visible and I tried below but it doesn't work

```
UPDATE category c 
            LEFT JOIN portfolio_job_category pjc
            ON pjc.category_id = c.id
            LEFT JOIN job j
            ON j.id = pjc.job_id
            SET c.visible = 0
            WHERE (c.visible = 0 
            OR c.visible IS NULL)
            AND j.end_date > CURRENT_DATE
            GROUP BY cat_id
```

Comment: group by is not needed there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is not part of the grammar for `UPDATE` statements ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)). `GROUP BY` as part of an update doesn't make a lot of sense, because there are no aggregate functions involved. If your aim is just to update all categories that are associated with jobs that haven't ended yet, you should be able to accomplish this with just the joins you have.

Also, the `c.visible = 0` portion of the disjunction in the `WHERE` clause seems redundant. No need to set visible to 0 if it's already 0.